# Mayan EDMS not working on browser but Nginx and Supervisor is up and running

Tags: python-2.7, mayanedms

I just installed Mayan-EDMS on my Ubuntu 16.06 LTS, the services of Nginx and Supervisor are up and running but I can't see it working on the browser, can someone help me out on this?

Please see error log below.

---

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'/tmp/bbe634d59fe221a7c66f1575eb5214c1c49a3e40ff10d6c8149c25cc217a7d0d'

celery beat v3.1.24 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
. broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
. loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
. scheduler -> djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

. logfile -> [stderr]@%ERROR
. maxinterval -> now (0s)
celery beat v3.1.24 (Cipater) is starting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Probably means you installed Mayan EDMS using one user and are running it using another user account.

The file in the /tmp folder is probably the lock file.

To fix the issue, stop Mayan and delete the`/tmp/bbe634d59fe221a7c66f1575eb5214c1c49a3e40ff10d6c8149c25cc217a7d0d` file. It will be created again by the user running the Mayan server subsequently.

Comment: Even though I didn't see this answer on time, that was exactly what I did and it was resolved. Thanks.